# How to insert multiple items at once when not all of them match the constraints?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, sqlite, constraints, bulkinsert

I'm using `InsertAllOnSubmit` but when it fails, because an item doesn't obey the constraints, no item is inserted.

Is there a way of inserting all valid items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use  `INSERT OR IGNORE`

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do that is to not allow the user to marshall invalid data in the first place. That's something the user interface does by acting in concert with the database. For example, if the user is expected to supply the name of a city in California, the user interface should

- implement a pick list (aka combo box)
  containing only the names of cities
  in Californian, or
- let the user enter anything, check to
  see whether the entered value is a
  city in California, and return an
  informative error message if it's not
- other things I can't think of right now, because I'm sleepy

The other normal way is to submit each "row" or "set" of data as individual transactions. Invalid data will rollback only its own transaction, not the whole batch. This affects performance; it's almost always faster to insert 1000 rows as one transaction of 1000 rows rather than as 1000 transactions of one row each.